# How to save status the youtube dl to the .txt file

Tags: php, youtube-dl

I have a script using [youtube dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl). The script downloads the file and converts it to the mp3 format. I would like to write in the .txt file the status in which the phase is, for example:
- downloading
- converting
- finished

My script:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yU0tnrEk8H4';
exec('youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 '.$url,  $output, $ret)
print_r($output);
print_r($ret);
?>
```

Do you have any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Why would you download videos from YouTube? To steal the content?

Comment: No, your answer is not for subject. I do it for educational purposes